# MIPS multiplication using addition

Tags: mips

sorry, I try to multiply two integers but it doesn't work. I can't find where the problem is.Maybe because of register' names but I don't know how to correct it. I correct many times but it is not successful. Could anyone give me some points?

```
.data
prompt1: .asciiz "Please enter the first signed (decimal) integer: "
prompt2: .asciiz "Please enter the second signed (decimal) integer: "
result_msg: .asciiz "The result of these two 16-bit integers\' multiplication is: "
.text
.globl main
main:
      li $v0, 4        #print prompt
      la $a0, prompt1
      syscall

      li $v0, 5        #read multiplicand 
      syscall
      move $s0, $v0

      li $v0, 4        #print prompt
      la $a0, prompt2
      syscall

      li $v0, 5      #read multiplier
      syscall
      move $s1, $v0

Mult: ori $t0,$zero,1  #mask
      move $s3, $0    #initialize the result register
      move $t1, $0


loop: beq $s1, $zero, end  #if the multiplier is 0 then finished
      and $t1, $t0, $s1      #mask
      beq $t1, 1, mult_add   
      beq $t1, 0, shift

mult_add:  addu $s3, $s3, $s0     #add to get product

shift: 
      sll $s0, $s0, 1    #shift multiplicand left
      srl $s1, $s1, 1    #shift multiplier right

      j loop

end:
     jr $ra                

result:                            #input the print_string
      li $v0, 4
      la $a0, result_msg
      syscall


exit:
      li $v0, 1            #input result
      move $a0, $s3
      syscall

      li $v0, 10        #exit
      syscall
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inspecting your code I see that you jump to label `end` when you are done multiplying.

The instruction at that label issues a `jr $ra` which *"returns from a function"*, but I guess you just want to print the result and exit.

Therefore I'd suggest you remove that instruction so as to print the result and exit and maybe remove label `result` as it is not used anywhere in your code.

Comment: Thank you very much! It can work! In addition, could you tell me how to multiply signed integers? I am a beginner and I don' t know how to handle it. Sorry for more question.:)

Comment: @sakurababy: the algorithm for unsigned and (A2-compliment) signed integers is exactly the same. So if your program works for unsigned integers it should also work for signed integers