# How can I perform multiplication in MIPS assembly using shift and add?

Tags: assembly, mips

Please help, I've spent over 5 hours trying to figure out this simple problem and I cannot for the life of me figure out how the hell you do it.

I am supposed to do some problem like 7 * 5 and return the result in MIPS assembly, but I HAVE to do it using shift and add. I cannot figure out how to use the hint we were given and turn it into MIPS code. Like I understand 100% how the picture below works and the logic behind it, but I CANNOT turn it into MIPS assembly code, thats what I've spent over 5 hours trying to do.

[here is what we were given as a hint](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lv0oM.png)

I understand how shifting works, I understand how adding works in MIPS, I just don't know how I can do what is shown in that image, in MIPS assembly language. (I don't know how to turn the english into code that does that stuff. MIPS is too barebones for this!)

I SHOULD CLARIFY!: Both numbers are VARIABLES. I don't know how to write the code that takes two differing numbers each time and gets the result, using shift and add. 7*5, 6*9, 17*3, etc. Whatever the user enters for those two numbers as long as they are non-negative, the code must get the result.

Comment: This is a question you should ask your instructor.  `sll` and `addu` are straightforward to use in MIPS.  It sounds like you're asking for someone to explain the basic concepts of assembly language.  I don't think it's possible for this question to have a good answer that fits the stackoverflow format.

Comment: I think you need to reread the question. I understand how to use both of those, as I clearly said in my question, its translating the larger problem of doing multiplication USING those two commands that I am struggling with. Shift left essentially multiplies the number by 2 every time you shift. Adding literally adds numbers and stores them into a new register. Now how do I use those to multiply numbers together. I see from the image I posted a way to do that, but I don't know how to represent that in MIPS assembly code.

Comment: 7 * 4 = `li $t0,7` (or `addi $t0, $zero, 7` if for whatever reason you don't have pseudo instructions) `sll $t0, $t0, 2` .. yaaay, `t0 = 28`. (in binary `t0 = 00000111`, then after `sll`: `t0 = 00011100` = old value shifted left by 2 bits).

Comment: Thanks but BOTH numbers are variables. So I have to adapt the code to multiply 21 * 7, or 3 * 7, or 2 * 3, etc.

Comment: Another hint is ... imagine you have one temp register reserved as bit-mask, starting with value `1`. Now in each loop you copy value `b` into another temp register, mask (`and` instruction) it with the mask value, and then you either do something or not, depending if the result is not equal to zero. Then at the end of the loop you can do `sll ...,1` to both bit mask, and value `a`... (or other way, do right shift to `b`, keep mask at `1`, and loop till `b` is zeroed by right shift.  ... try it on paper with few values, what happens.

Comment: You know that 5*3 basically means 3 + 3 + 3 + 3 + 3 and 11 * 3 is basically 10 * 3 + 3.

Comment: @Jonasw yes, but that's not what is expected in solution. He should calculate that as (5<<1) + (5<<0). (or (3<<2) + (3<<0) ).   @ OP: 5h is not that much.. take a break, take a walk, re-read some older lectures, etc... re-read our comments... take a paper and pen, and toy around a bit with binary numbers... It's hard to help you more without simply writing the code instead of you, it's sort of "obvious" once you will see it.  ... if really desperate, try to think first how you would count number of bits in user entered value.

Comment: https://pastebin.com/wycRRtrE This is what my code looks like. @Ped7g I've been trying something very very similar to what you're saying, but it seemed too convoluted to work. Does it look like i'm even on the right track? I will try writing it on paper

Comment: No, not far, but going a bit off, you are overcomplicating it.. the inner loop should look quite simple, like ~4 instruction by feel, which means there will be like more like 6-8 of them, but it should be as simple as the image hint.. actually simpler, because the hint contains all steps of loop together, while you can create loop doing just one operation, and loop through one of values as multiplier. (for example you shouldn't need to know whether the input value was odd, but that kind of test can be used to detect if particular bit is set in value)

Comment: You didn't say in the question you had to handle variable inputs.  Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33672323/mips-multiplication-using-addition.  For the simpler case of multiplying by a constant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18812319/multiplication-using-logical-shifts-in-mips-assembly.  Those are just the first couple google hits.

Comment: @Ped7g https://pastebin.com/G4SD0rEV this got so much worse...

Comment: @dmscs yeah, half of it doesn't make sense. ... still having some "odd status" ... and when second number is even, it will jump straight to `results` ... are you just adding instructions randomly? Try rather construct the algorithm (formulas) in math language first. ... Also things like `add $s3, $s0, $zero` vs `move $s2, $zero` are puzzling me, why do you use one time `add` and then `move` for the same thing, it's inconsistent, making the source harder to read and reason about it. The pseudo-ins. `move` reads well, although seasoned MIPS coder will know there's real `add` behind it.

Answer (score 1):

I grade school we learned that a * (b + c) = ab + ac right?  So 7 * 5 = 7 * (4 + 1) = 7*4 + 7*1 which are both powers of 2...(2^2 and 2^0).

If not a constant does it matter?

```
     abcd
*    efgh
==========
     abcd  * h
    abcd   * g
   abcd    * f
+ abcd     * e
=============
```

same stuff we learned in grade school except much simpler as efgh are either zero or one.  So if the h bit (bit 0) then we add abcd<<0, if the g bit is set (bit 1) then add abcd<<1 if f is set (bit 2) then add abcd<<2 and so on.

So actually you do/did know how to do it just not how to apply it.  Pencil and paper just like grade school, no reason to spend 5 hours...

EDIT

```
unsigned int a,b,x,y;
for(y=0,x=0;x<32;x++) if(a&(1<<x)) y+=b<<x;


for(y=0,x=1,z=b;x;x<<=1,z<<=1) if(x&a) y+=z;
```

Comment: This isn't working for me when I try to do 2 x 2. If 10 is 2 in binary, then I end up with something like this: 10 + (10 << 1) when I try to solve it. That will equal 6 though, not 4.

Comment: @dmscs You should end up doing  1*(10<<1) + 0*(10<<0) (each shifted value (multiplied by power of two) is multiplied by 0 or 1, depending whether that bit is set or not in multiplier (here 1* and 0* form the original "10" of second value).. how to do *0 and *1 without multiplication is clear I hope).

Comment: @dmscs You did 2*3 not 2*2  you added to the accumulator assuming each of the second operands bits were set.

Comment: what part do you not understand?  shifing a register?  anding? testing for zero? addition?  not going to do your homework for you.  show us what you have so far and what you think it is doing.

Answer (score 0):

For the effort shown, I will put here major spoiler, but you will probably regret it, once you will realise how you were running in circles around solution.

```
s0 = a, s1 = b, s2 = 0 (will be result)
multiply_loop:
  if (s1 == 0) goto output_result
  t1 = s1&1
  if (t1 == 0) goto skip_add
  s2 += s0
skip_add:
  s0 <<= 1;  multiply "a" by 2
  s1 >>= 1;  shift bits of "b" to right by 1 for s1&1 test
  goto multiply_loop

output_result:
  s2 is result of multiplication
```

Of course this will overflow for big "a"/"b" values, etc.. Try it decipher on paper first, with binary values, how it works internally.

Comment: I understand but it looks like it did not work when I converted it to mips. https://pastebin.com/KN7kP9u3 doing 2 * 5 gives me 16 as the result

Comment: https://pastebin.com/qFx7iuUs sorry my brain is so fried at this point I made some mistakes because I typed this off an older version. This is what it looks like now, and I still get the wrong answer of 5 * 2 = 5

Comment: Yes, that's what your code will do. You have to add to result the shifted value, not the original one. Each loop the value shifts more and more, thus at *i*-th loop the `s0` is equal to (a << (i-1)), while your `s3` remains equal to "a" all the time. Judging by the system calls you are doing this in MARS or SPIM, both have debuggers available. If you would stare at the values for a while, you would probably find you are doing s2 = s2 + s3 where s2 = 0 + 5, while s0 is equal to 10 at that moment. Just single-step in debugger over the code and watch everything. You missed the main idea (a*=2).

Comment: Ugh. I fixed it. It was all my fault as expected. I'm so disappointed in myself

Comment: @dmscs it's normal with assembly programming. It's quite unforgiving and every detail matters... anyway, it doesn't matter how many times you fail, it doesn't even matter that it supposedly works now, what counts is, whether you understood how you can produce such solution on yourself. Maybe try again to go through all the comments and hints now, if you can better understand them. The one about taking a walk was also important (to not fry your brain too early).

Comment: @dmscs as a mini bonus task: figure out how to extend that algorithm to have better performance on average. I.e. figure out how long it takes to multiply values now (in O(...) terms, not perfect CPU cycles), the O(...) is upper limit, so it will cover all possible inputs, but sometimes you may uncover more detailed runtime characteristic, so look on possible inputs if there's some performance-relevant categorization and how it goes. From there you should be able to find out tiny addition which will on average improve the performance of this algorithm, especially for non-overflowing inputs.